# SWT drop down menu button visual glitch

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, swt, visual-glitch

I am having trouble with a visual glitch on my two drop down menus in my toolbar. When I:

1. Scroll my mouse pointer over the `File` drop down menu button...

   [image]
2. Scroll across to the `Options` drop down menu button...

   [image]
3. Scroll off the toolbar entirely...

   [image]

The File dropdown button remains highlighted, although, it doen't seem to be in focus. This happens to the Options drop down menu as well if you scroll from the `Options` to the `File` and then off the toolbar.

Here is the code that creates the `ToolBar` and `ToolItems`

```
final ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar (mainshell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
toolBar.setSize(200,35);
toolBar.setLocation(0,0);
    
ToolItem File = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
File.setText("File");
final Menu FdropMenu = new Menu(mainshell, SWT.POP_UP);
File.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e1) {
        if (e1.detail == SWT.ARROW) {
            final ToolItem FtoolItem = (ToolItem) e1.widget;
            final ToolBar  FtoolBar = FtoolItem.getParent();
            Point point = FtoolBar.toDisplay(new Point(e1.x, e1.y));
            FdropMenu.setLocation(point.x, point.y);
            FdropMenu.setVisible(true);
        } 
    }
}); 
     
final MenuItem SaveMI = new MenuItem(FdropMenu, SWT.PUSH);
final MenuItem OpenMI = new MenuItem(FdropMenu, SWT.PUSH);
 
ToolItem itemDrop = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
itemDrop.setText("Options");
final Menu dropMenu = new Menu(mainshell, SWT.POP_UP);
itemDrop.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.detail == SWT.ARROW) {
            final ToolItem toolItem = (ToolItem) e.widget;
            final ToolBar  toolBar = toolItem.getParent();
            Point point = toolBar.toDisplay(new Point(e.x, e.y));
            dropMenu.setLocation(point.x, point.y);
            dropMenu.setVisible(true);
        } 
    }
});
```

I am not sure if this is an error in my programming or a bug in SWT. Any support would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post links of the images you mention. We can embed them if necessary.

Comment: Here are the links I was given when I uploaded the files. I could not post them directly on the article because of the two link limit.http://i.stack.imgur.com/2aRoC.png,  

http://i.stack.imgur.com/wHEPz.png,

http://i.stack.imgur.com/br8q4.png

Comment: @JayCodeBuilder Are you sure it's not just a focus issue, i.e. the file menu item having the focus?

Comment: @Baz I don't think so, I am testing that right now.

Comment: @Baz MenuItems in SWT cannot have focus and scrolling over the toolbar does not give it focus.

Comment: @JayCodeBuilder They can have focus, it has focus when I start the application (on Linux) and the focus moves when I press tab.

Comment: @Baz, maybe you are right, but I cannot set them to focused or add a focus listener to them in the code, I will keep experimenting though.

Comment: did you resolve this? because i'm having exactly the same problem

Comment: @l.moretto Unfortunately, no. I was unable to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I've discovered that if I use the `SWT.FLAT` style parameter in the `ToolBar` constructor this problem disappears.
Use this constructor in your code:

```java
ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar( parent, SWT.FLAT );
```